# Track Login and Logout Time of Every User In Salesforce and Community Users

Tags: apex, event, login, eventlogfile, login-history

For tracking login and logout of every user, people says to buy Event Monitoring licenses. We are not thinking to buy the licenses of event monitoring as we just wanted to track 2 event login and logout.

Isn't there any other way to track login and logout. We have implemented sso at our project.

**Login of user**: Create a login flow which will give you the user id of the user who is trying to login and then call a class from flows to query Login History (With status = success to get all the details of the logged in user)

**For Logout**: I saw "/event/LogoutEventStream" is the only event available in my sandbox as we have not buyied the event monitoring licenses. Is "/event/LogoutEventStream" event is free for all? If yes, what are the limitations on the number of logouts ? Or any other limitation anyone aware of.

Comment: Login History tracks logins, including SSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is "/event/LogoutEventStream" event is free for all?

It is free for Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Edition orgs. These orgs get the API Total Usage, CORS Violation Record, Hostname Redirects, Insecure External Assets, Login, and Logout for free. This is mentioned in [EventLogFile Supported Event Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm).

> If yes, what are the limitations on the number of logouts ? Or any other limitation anyone aware of.

The free Platform Events included above have a 1 day retention policy. Getting the paid version of Platform Events extends the retention period to 30 days, and provides access to all of the [Event Monitoring types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm).

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, is there any document where it is written as Login, Logout, and API Usage Events are free? Dont know why my sandbox only showing "/event/LogoutEventStream". Also for retention policy i understood you point. Just one question on limitation, i hope unlike platform events, if as many as 2 lakh customers logged in 1 day or 1 month the events will still fire right?